# How do I improve 'ELI5: Explain work hours to young adult'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, editing

How do I improve this question please?

[ELI5: Explain work hours to young adult](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/160750/eli5-explain-work-hours-to-young-adult)

(answer gets 9 upvotes and question gets 9 downvotes. so much for this [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions). ostensibly, basically the community gets whatever benefit from this question I'm not allowed to delete and yet the asker bears the burden of having question privilege removed. Ok well yeah if it's such a dumb question, then it seems weird to answer or to upvote answers instead of just commenting to vote to close. Ok. fine.)

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't seem bad to me. Weird, certainly. Probably a duplicate of something that's been asked before. Strange focus on music lyrics. But still a reasonably clear, answerable question.

Comment: possibly related: [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth I neither up- nor down-voted the question. I didn't answer it either.

I think there's probably an on-topic core question in there somewhere, and I think you got a solid answer. While you focus on the 9 downvotes the question received you neglect that it also got 5 upvotes, so the response was far from being uniformly bad.  So when you say:

> Ok well yeah if it's such a dumb question, then it seems weird to answer or to upvote answers instead of just commenting to vote to close. Ok. fine.)

I think you need to consider that the people downvoting your question quite possibly aren't the ones who answered and upvoted the answer. So the hypocrisy you perceive probably doesn't exist.

> How do I improve this question please?

I'd say the question would benefit from less focus/space given to quoting songs as well as focusing on a more concrete problem/goal.

Comment: While I think your answer's right, only the last line of your post actually answers the main question here of how to improve the post. You should edit it to elaborate on that point (e.g. by pointing out that the quoted song lyrics just add clutter to the post). In addition, I'd also point out that it's unclear what the actual problem being solved is; the framing device of "ELI5" just obscures that even further (as pointed out in the [Software Engineering Meta Q&A](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6629) that's linked in the comments of this question).